# hibernate query issue, so close and stumped

Tags: hibernate, collections, hql

The schema:
(psuedocode)

I have a bean, called BaseEntity...

```
@Entity
class BaseEntity {
   @OneToMany @CascadeType.ALL
   List [Property] properties;
   //the use angled braces ommited for the stackoverflow editor to show up properly
}
```

Property is another bean...

```
@Entity
class Property {
   @ManyToOne
   Category category;
   @OneToOne
   Value value;
}
```

Value is actually an abstract class with Inheritence.SingleTable and subclasses like NumericalValue and DateValue, etc, as well as (in the abstract Value class) a @ManyToOne BaseType type.

#### The goal:

I am trying to write a query that selects BaseEntity objects that have a Property that has a Category of a certain name, and select several of them, getting objects that have any of the given properties and getting null in fields that don't exist.

#### The attempt:

```
select entity.id as id, foo as foo, bar as bar 
from BaseEntity entity, Value foo, Value bar 
where foo in (select p.value from Property p where p in elements(entity.properties) and p.category.name = 'FOO') 
or bar in (select p.value from Property p where p in elements(entity.properties) and p.category.name = 'BAR')
```

This query DOES run.  Currently there is one BaseEntity in the database that matches and I get it many times over with with the correct result for foo, which it does contain, but that same entitiy over and over again with many values in the bar field.

Also, it takes like FIVE MINUTES to run and holds up everyone else using the database.

Ideas:

Of course I have considered just using some kind of distinct, but that doesn't address the extreme time it takes to run, and I just don't quite understand what's going on.

I was hoping you, my peers, could suggest a better query approach.  Thank you so much!

---

I would have commented, but this code is too long for the comment box... I ran a query, this one is not so long that it hangs, but any more joins and it does hang instead of completing... this query takes MINUTES to execute.

I ran the query from my code and turned on show_sql in the hibernate properties.

select baseentity0_.entityId as col_0_0_, property2_.value_valueId as col_1_0_, property4_.value_valueId as col_2_0_, property6_.value_valueId as col_3_0_, property8_.value_valueId as col_4_0_, property10_.value_valueId as col_5_0_, value11_.valueId as valueId9_0_, value12_.valueId as valueId9_1_, value13_.valueId as valueId9_2_, value14_.valueId as valueId9_3_, value15_.valueId as valueId9_4_, value11_.type_typeId as type6_9_0_, value11_.numericalValue as numerica3_9_0_, value11_.textValue as textValue9_0_, value11_.dateValue as dateValue9_0_, value11_.value_entityId as value7_9_0_, value11_.DTYPE as DTYPE9_0_, value12_.type_typeId as type6_9_1_, value12_.numericalValue as numerica3_9_1_, value12_.textValue as textValue9_1_, value12_.dateValue as dateValue9_1_, value12_.value_entityId as value7_9_1_, value12_.DTYPE as DTYPE9_1_, value13_.type_typeId as type6_9_2_, value13_.numericalValue as numerica3_9_2_, value13_.textValue as textValue9_2_, value13_.dateValue as dateValue9_2_, value13_.value_entityId as value7_9_2_, value13_.DTYPE as DTYPE9_2_, value14_.type_typeId as type6_9_3_, value14_.numericalValue as numerica3_9_3_, value14_.textValue as textValue9_3_, value14_.dateValue as dateValue9_3_, value14_.value_entityId as value7_9_3_, value14_.DTYPE as DTYPE9_3_, value15_.type_typeId as type6_9_4_, value15_.numericalValue as numerica3_9_4_, value15_.textValue as textValue9_4_, value15_.dateValue as dateValue9_4_, value15_.value_entityId as value7_9_4_, value15_.DTYPE as DTYPE9_4_ from BaseEntity baseentity0_ inner join BaseEntity_Property properties1_ on baseentity0_.entityId=properties1_.BaseEntity_entityId inner join Property property2_ on properties1_.properties_propertyId=property2_.propertyId inner join Value value11_ on property2_.value_valueId=value11_.valueId inner join BaseEntity_Property properties3_ on baseentity0_.entityId=properties3_.BaseEntity_entityId inner join Property property4_ on properties3_.properties_propertyId=property4_.propertyId inner join Value value12_ on property4_.value_valueId=value12_.valueId inner join BaseEntity_Property properties5_ on baseentity0_.entityId=properties5_.BaseEntity_entityId inner join Property property6_ on properties5_.properties_propertyId=property6_.propertyId inner join Value value13_ on property6_.value_valueId=value13_.valueId inner join BaseEntity_Property properties7_ on baseentity0_.entityId=properties7_.BaseEntity_entityId inner join Property property8_ on properties7_.properties_propertyId=property8_.propertyId inner join Value value14_ on property8_.value_valueId=value14_.valueId inner join BaseEntity_Property properties9_ on baseentity0_.entityId=properties9_.BaseEntity_entityId inner join Property property10_ on properties9_.properties_propertyId=property10_.propertyId inner join Value value15_ on property10_.value_valueId=value15_.valueId, Category category16_, Category category17_, Category category18_, Category category19_, Category category20_ where property2_.category_categoryId=category16_.categoryId and property4_.category_categoryId=category17_.categoryId and property6_.category_categoryId=category18_.categoryId and property8_.category_categoryId=category19_.categoryId and property10_.category_categoryId=category20_.categoryId and category16_.name='Sample Name / Strain' and category17_.name='Item #' and category18_.name='THC_Result' and category19_.name='CBD_Result' and category20_.name='CBN_Result'

---

Well, I wanted to follow up and say that what worked wonderfully with two join statements is absurdly sluggish with five.

`select 
    entity.id as entityId,
    strain.value as name,
    item.value as itemNum,
    thc.value as THC, 
    cbd.value as CBD, 
    cbn.value as CBN`

from BaseEntity as entity 
join entity.properties as strain
join entity.properties as item
join entity.properties as thc 
join entity.properties as cbd
join entity.properties as cbn
where strain.category.name = 'Sample Name / Strain' 
and item.category.name = 'Item #'
and thc.category.name = 'THC_Result' 
and cbd.category.name = 'CBD_Result'
and cbn.category.name = 'CBN_Result'

Any suggestions on a better way to do it that will be faster with my stupid schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance problem looks like it is in your sub selects.

What about breaking it up a bit

```
select entity from BaseEntity as entity join entity.properties as property where
property.category.name in ( 'FOO','BAR' )
```

This would get you the list of Base Entities with a property of FOO or BAR then if you wanted to limit the collections of baseEntity.properties use a filter or requery to get the properties.

```
from properity where  property.category.name in ( 'FOO', 'BAR' )
and property.baseEntity.priKey = :priKey
```

Comment: wow, that gets me SO close to the results I need!  The problem is I am using this to poulate a Jasper Report, so returned object will be a field in the report.

This query:

select entity.id, property.category, property.value from BaseEntity as entity join entity.properties as property 
where property.category.name in ( 'FOO', 'BAR' )

gets the values I need, but I need to return BOTH the property.value of the property where property.category.name = 'FOO' AND the corresponding value of BAR in the same record, each as fields for the report!

So close, please and thank you!

Comment: ie, I need each BaseEntity *only once* with one field for the value of 'FOO' and one field for the value of 'BAR'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you override the default fetch types for the associations? Usually this leads to the issue. Can you post the query Hibernate generates?

Comment: oh, I don't override nearly any fetch types!  good question... so far I've been running that query from an eclipse hibernate query window to test it... haven't run it through my app to show_sql...

Answer (score 0):

It was absolutely ccclark's answer that got me in the direction, and my good friend helped too...

```
select entity.id as entityId, entity.type as entityType, p1.value as Vendor, p2.value as Weight 
from BaseEntity as entity 
join entity.properties as p1 
join entity.properties as p2 
where p1.category.name = 'Vendor' and p2.category.name = 'Total Weight'
```

does EXACTLY what I need.
THANK YOU STACKOVERFLOW COMMUNITY!

Answer (score 0):

That query looks reasonable to me.  So the question is:

What SQL is hibernate producing for that HQL?

What query plan is the database producing for that SQL?

In Sybase or MS SQL Server:  "set showplan on".
In Oracle use SQLDeveloper/Toad and select the plan/Ambulance.

It is likely that you need to use an index on category name in the category table, and an index on category id and entity id in the properties table, and the primary keys, value id in the values table.

Comment: I have added an index to the category.name field... Category is probably the least edited table in the db.  the Property table is very heavily used, with most of the data fields in the db passing through it.